# Oracle SQL - Help putting a table together

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

part of my learning process, I am taking as much data  I have on my computer and trying to use it to practice Oracle SQL. So I am in charge of keeping track of the Home Owner association money, I created a table with the following columns:

```
Name               Null? Type         
------------------ ----- ------------ 
OWNER_NAME               VARCHAR2(20) 
APPARTEMENT_NUMBER       NUMBER(4)    
TELEPHONE_NUMBER         NUMBER(15)   
JULY                     NUMBER(5)    
AUGUST                   NUMBER(5)    
SEPTEMBER                NUMBER(5)    
OCTOBER                  NUMBER(5)    
NOVEMBER                 NUMBER(5)    
DECEMBER                 NUMBER(5)
```

but I don't know how to do the following:

I need a way to track if the apt number paid its HOA fees, my idea is to have a check box and check it if the fee is paid and uncheck it if the fee is not paid. I'm just thinking out loud.

Please help
Thank you

Comment: As @Littlefoot said, your data model flawed, primarily because you should not have individual columns for months.  What is it you plan on putting in those columns - what does each represent?  Depending on the answer to that, you should, as Littlefoot said, replace them with a single column of type DATE, or possibly break them off into a child talble of some some description.  It all depends on what those columns are tracking.

Comment: those columns are tracking H.O.A monthly fees that I keep track for my building.

Comment: So, is that fees actually paid each month?  If so I'd suggest a child table FEE_PAYMENTS, with columns OWNER_ID (number) PAID_DATED (type DATE) and  PAID_AMT (number).  Your main table should also have OWENER_ID (number) as a primary key, and FEE_PAYMENTS.OWNER_ID is a foreign key back to OWNER_ID of your main table.

Comment: but why have a child table where the payment is one flat fixed payment every month?

Comment: I assumed that it was tracking whether the payment had actually been made. If it is just to record what the payment _is_, and it is a fixed amount every month, why have the monthly columns in your base table?

Comment: I will try your way and see how it goes.

Comment: No, don't try my way just yet.  You indicated that the monthly information was actually recording the amount of the monthly due, but it was a fixed amount every month. So I asked you to question why you need multiple month buckets _at all_ .. regardless of if they are multiple columns in one table or multiple rows in a child table.  That question was not facetious.  It is a serious design question that you need to answer in order to properly design your table(s).

Comment: @EdStevens I don't need multiple Month Buckets, I only did what I did to get started. I was completely confused on how to get it started but thanks to all of you now everything is clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data model looks wrong. You shouldn't have *months* as column names - use only one `DATE` datatype column because - this one will be OK for this year. What about the next year? How will you know which "July" is it? Or, if that column contains only [month + year] info, make it VARCHAR2(6).

Phone number (and probably apartment number as well) should be *strings* because of leading zeros (in phone numbers) or letters in apartment numbers.

As of the "checkbox", there's no such datatype, but you can use `NUMBER` (1 - checkbox checked; 0 - not checked) or `CHAR` (Y / N) for that purpose.

Something like this:

```
create table hoa_fees
  (owner_name       varchar2(20),
   apartment_number varchar2(4),
   telephone_number varchar2(15),
   month_year       varchar2(6),                    -- e.g. 102020
   fee              number,                         -- money here
   cb_paid          number(1) default 0 not null    -- e.g. 1 - paid
  );
```

Comment: I would argue against the MONTH_YEAR and go with (as you originally proposed) a pure DATE column.  Call it SOMETHING_DATE, where SOMETHING says whatever it is that date is tracking.